# Get SQL execute cmd duration in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I run a simple SQL query command though I want to know if it is possible to retrieve, in C#, the duration (the amount of time it took SQL to run the query) without having to look at the command through SQL profiler.

Comment: One option is to wrap the execution with a `Stopwatch` and use that to report the time taken from the app side. This would not be the same as the execution time at the SQL server of course, as it would include network overhead.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the command, so I think the stopwatch is probably the only thing you can do. If you're worried about network latency or other overhead, try running a `select 1` query through a bunch of times, which should have practically zero duration, and whatever the average of what your stopwatch tells you, that's your latency/overhead on real queries.

Comment: Not really answering to the exact question, but from plan cache you can see average duration per statement (and CPU and I/O usage) as long as the plan hasn't been removed from cache.

Comment: You can turn on page tracing and see how long the method took to execute, but that will include whatever else you're doing in there...if you're in a multi-tiered application this may not be too accurate.

Comment: you may be able to query the sys.dm_exec_query_stats to get the statistics for the query.  It might be easier than capturing the output from set statistics time on.  You need permissions for it though.

Comment: Can't we use `glimpse` to get the time

Comment: `context.Database.Log` logs the duration of each SQL command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

// stuff here

Stopwatch _ProcessTimer = new Stopwatch();
_ProcessTimer.Start();

// do the thang

_ProcessTimer.Stop();

// now use _ProcessTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds or another property
```

See MSDN page for [Stopwatch Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want elapsed time then a stopwatch as mentioned by @JoeEnos will do, but if you want actual CPU used by SQL Server then you could use [SET STATISTICS TIME ON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx) and capture and parse the output.

No specific permissions are required to use SET STATISTICS TIME.

Comment: Can you please share what permissions are required. Because we typically give the user the `dbaccessadmin`,`dbdatareader`and `dbdatawriter` permissions

Comment: If anyway for achieving this in EF is highly useful to me and others

Answer (score 0):

MiniProfiler has such functionality out of the box. I would consider using it if you're developing an ASP.NET application. 
See [the main page](http://miniprofiler.com/) of this library for more details.